# Will a stress-energy tensor have the same identities as it's metric?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Say I have a metric tensor where $$g_{00} = -c^{2}\ 
and $$  $$g_{01}=g_{02}=g_{03}=0$$ and $$g_{12}=g_{13}=g_{23}$$ and $$g_{11}=g_{22}=g_{33}$$
My question is straightforward: would the same or similar identities apply to the stress energy tensor?

Comment: No. Just try to check this for the scalar stress tensor.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is no, but if $g_{12}=const, g_{11}=const$ and there is a cosmological constant then yes. To see this recall the Einstein field equations
$$ R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}.$$

Now if the metric is constant then the Ricci tensor and Ricci curvature is trivial and we get

$$ \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu} $$
so all the symmetry properties of the metric are the same for the stress-energy tensor.

However in general for non-constant metric you need to calculate the Ricci tensor which can be done in some mathematical packages like Mathematica, Maple.